# Aptana shows a warning "input proprietary attribute onclick"

Tags: onclick, aptana

When entering a code line in Aptana Studio like

> `<input id="send" type="button" value="Send" onclick="calculate()" />`

Aptana shows a warning: "input proprietary attribute onclick".

I wonder if this is a bug. There was a similar problem just a few days ago:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4873 called
"'button proprietary attribute onclick' is invalid warning"

Version: Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.3.201205292243

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is covered in that JIRA ticket and resolved in the latest nightly build of Aptana Studio 3.2.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my update preferences I did not check the nightly updates. Now, things are fine  :)